# What bookkeeping is caffe doing?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, backpropagation

Caffe [tutorial](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/net_layer_blob.html) states:

> The net is a set of layers connected in a computation graph – a directed acyclic graph (DAG) to be exact. *Caffe does all the bookkeeping* for any DAG of layers to ensure correctness of the forward and backward passes.

What is the meaning by "all the bookkeeping"?  I don't understand it.
How to do all the bookkeeping?

Answer (score 1):

Caffe, like many other deep-learning frameworks, trains its models using stochastic gradient decent (SGD), implemented as gradient back propagation. That is, for a mini-batch of training examples, caffe feed the batch through the net ("forward pass") to compute the loss w.r.t the net's parameters. Then, it propagates the loss gradient back ("backward pass") to update all the parameters according to the estimated gradient.

By "bookkeeping" the tutorial means, you do not need to worry about estimating the gradients and updating the parameters. Once you are using existing layers (e.g., `"Convolution"`, `"ReLU"`, `"Sigmoid"` etc.) you only need to define the graph structure (the net's architecture) and supply the training data, and caffe will take care of the rest of the training process: It will forward/backward each mini batch, compute the loss, estimate the gradients and update the parameters - all for you.
Pretty awesome, don't you think? ;)